# How to embed text on the bar of the highchart

Tags: highcharts

How to embedd text of the value on the column bar of the highchart

please see below image for the reference

[image http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1935/nbe1.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/1935/nbe1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are added via the [`dataLabels`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.dataLabels) method. Code would look something like:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                inside: false,
                rotation: 270,
                color: 'white',
                x: 3,
                y: 15
            }
        }
    },
```